# What crews are best for maximizing my heist returns?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I realized after the first heist that I could have made a better choice of crew in order to maximize my returns (since certain people end up costing more due to scripted events). Regardless of difficulty, what crew members should I choose in the heist missions in order to make the most money?

I know that the answer isn't always "pick the cheapest". E.g., on the jewel heist, the gunman with the least experience doesn't steal as much as the experienced one, and his casualty costs (in the scripted event) further cut into the take-home.

Comment: If we're ignoring difficulty, isn't the answer just "whoever's cheapest"?

Comment: @AnnaLear: I added to the question. No, the one with the smallest cut doesn't always maximize your cut

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thats What I Thought!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you know how all the heists go, or can catch on easy, try using the stupidest most cheapest crew available, their stats increase every time, just their cut stays at 8%